# 2010 automatic Renault clio won't turn over

Tags: transmission, renault, clio

I was driving my 2010 automatic clio the other day the car wouldn't change up from 1st to 2nd gear so I pulled over and stopped the car but it wouldn't turn over again and a "check gearbox" light came on. Anybody any idea what it could be I'm clueless

Comment: What do you see and hear when you try to start the engine?  Dash lights, clicking ....?

Comment: I'd guess that there's a problem with the gearbox and that the computer is preventing starting the engine so that the problem isn't made worse by driving it.